# ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/I0Itec/zkclient/serialize/ZkSerializer

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am doing kafka storm integration and while executing the storm code i am getting this error

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/I0Itec/zkclient/serialize/ZkSerializer
at kafka.api.OffsetRequest.writeTo(OffsetRequest.scala:65) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferSend.<init>(BoundedByteBufferSend.scala:43) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:171) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree3$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:152) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:151) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:66) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:73) ~[kafka-1.1.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.StaticCoordinator.<init>(StaticCoordinator.java:26) ~[kafka-1.1.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:74) ~[kafka-1.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3489$fn__3504.invoke(executor.clj:499) ~[storm-0.9.0-wip15.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__436.invoke(util.clj:375) ~[storm-0.9.0-wip15.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.I0Itec.zkclient.serialize.ZkSerializer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
... 13 common frames omitted
5083 [Thread-26] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - 
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/I0Itec/zkclient/serialize/ZkSerializer
at kafka.api.OffsetRequest.writeTo(OffsetRequest.scala:65) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferSend.<init>(BoundedByteBufferSend.scala:43) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:171) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree3$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:152) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:151) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:66) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:73) ~[kafka-1.1.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.StaticCoordinator.<init>(StaticCoordinator.java:26) ~[kafka-1.1.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:74) ~[kafka-1.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3489$fn__3504.invoke(executor.clj:499) ~[storm-0.9.0-wip15.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__436.invoke(util.clj:375) ~[storm-0.9.0-wip15.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.I0Itec.zkclient.serialize.ZkSerializer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
... 13 common frames omitted
5090 [Thread-13-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update:     :connected:none
5090 [Thread-10-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update:     :connected:none
5101 [Thread-13] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
5112 [Thread-10] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl -     Starting
5204 [Thread-26] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
```

i dont have zkclient in my pom file

what can be the proble? please help

Comment: How did you install Kafka, Storm-Kafka? Which Storm version and which Kafka version?

Comment: storm-0.9.0-wip16 and kafka-0.7.2-incubating-src

Comment: i believe version wont be a problem. i have executed the program before

Comment: Ok, without enough explanation, no one can helps you.

Comment: am sorrry.. i dont know what went wrong all of a sudden.. is it a problem with the zookeeper. im using the default zookeeper with kafka.

Comment: Are you building the Jar as 1 binary?

Answer (score 1):

You should have zkclient.jar in storm lib folder. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/101tec/zkclient/0.1.0/zkclient-0.1.0.jar should work. Else you should install a higher version of the jar. Kafka uses zkclient to communicate with Zookeeper. BTW, you should go for Kafka 0.8.0 as it has replication.

Comment: i added the jar file in storm lib folder.. tried with different versions also.. still same error

Comment: Nipun, the latest version of Kafka spout provided in storm contrib only support Kafka 0.7.0. See documention here: 
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/0.9.0-wip16b-scala292/storm-kafka

Comment: @Svend Correct. But we can easily write one ourselves. Actually, for my current project we are using Kafka 0.8.0 and Storm 0.9.0.1. We are using the high level Kafka consumers, which takes care of leader finding, consumer re-balancing, maintaining topic/partition/offsets on zookeeper etc.

Comment: That sounds cool!
Nipun, if your company decides to open source that spout, please let me know, there are indeed some cool feature in 0.8 we'd like to get ou r hands on :)

Comment: @Svend Unfortunately, we cannot open source that.

Comment: FYI, just heard about that Kafka 0.8 spout: 
https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus

Comment: @Svend That's really great. But I guess using Kafka high level consumers will simplify the stuffs a lot.